# Deleted AWS Athena driver in Dbeaver

Tags: amazon-web-services, dbeaver, amazon-athena

I accidentally deleted the AWS Athena driver which comes preinstalled in Dbeaver. I haven't found any way to restore it or to configure it again. Here's the things I've tried:

- Uninstall and install Dbeaver again.
- Configure the JDBC Driver for Athena myself following [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-jdbc.html) and the configuration I can see from Dbeaver's default Driver.
- Install it from zip linux.
- Verify folders in /usr/share/ to see that dbeaver is indeed erased.

Nothing of these worked. Have anyone gone through the same trouble? I'm using KDE Neon 5.25.